# delete memory allocated with lua_newuserdata

Tags: c, memory, lua, garbage-collection

When does Lua gc memory allocated in C with

```
void *lua_newuserdata (lua_State *L, size_t size);
```

? 
When there is no reference in Lua pointing to it anymore or do I have to take care about deleting it?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as garbage-collection in C but I don't know lua enough to know what happens to what it manages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory allocated with `lua_newuserdata` is freed when there are no references to it *inside* Lua. This is how garbage collection works. There are important consequences:

1. No need to free that memory in your C program. No need to worry about freeing it at all.
2. Don't free that memory.
3. Don't store a pointer to that memory in your C program and assume it is valid forever.
4. If you want to use that pointer, make sure there is a reference to it in Lua.

In other words, after calling `lua_newuserdata` you need to store that userdata value somewhere in Lua (a global variable, a table entry, a function upvalue) if you're going to use it later in your C program. Otherwise it may vanish after you return to Lua.

Answer (score 7):

`lua_newuserdata` allocates memory but does not give C ownership of it. You can use it as you see fit, but should not free it; it will be freed automatically by lua once there are no more references to the userdata object.

The corollary to this is that if you are keeping pointers to it around for a long time in C, you have to be careful that Lua doesn't collect it while you're still using it. Make sure not to remove all Lua references to the userdata until you're done using it from C - or, conversely, use the `__gc` metamethod to make sure C gets informed when the object is collected.

Answer (score 2):

Lua indeed allocates memory but does not give you the ownership of this allocated memory. So the short answer is: no, do not free the memory allocated by Lua.